# How to generate doxygen call graph that includes class methods?

Tags: c++, doxygen, call-graph

I have a huge C++ project developed by someone else which I'm trying to get a good view with doxygen.
I managed to properly configure doxygen to generate everything I need, except the callgraphs. They only show auxiliary functions, not the others class methods.

Is there a way to show also the class methods?

PS: [this](http://pastebin.com/37Xw24SV) is my `doxyfile`

Best

Comment: do you use doxywizard? There might be an option in there.

Comment: I never heard about it, I updated the question with the doxyfile

Comment: looks legit, no clue. Try the doxygen mailing list, it looks pretty active.